# How to create drilldowns in Kibana in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, elastic-stack

I am implementing a logging solution using the elastic stack in AWS, I want to create a drilldown but the option does not show up.

I have done it previously in Elastic Cloud

What could be causing than this option doesn't show up?

P.D.: I am using version 7.10

Comment: Have you checked whether the feature you're missing is x-pack? Even free features are mostly covered by their proprietary open-source license these days.

Comment: I've just looked it up - drilldowns [are x-pack](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/drilldowns.html#drilldowns). AWS uses the BSD-licensed version, without any x-pack features... not even the free ones